# Where does a controller define what template or view is rendered for a certain action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

A controller has many objects itself and so do the request / response objects. One of those must define the view that is rendered when a certain action is invoked.

Can you tell me where this is defined?

Yours sincerely

von Spotz

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action

Comment: If you have a specific problem then you have to describe this specific problem in your question, maybe I'll be able to answer it in that case (if I want to, obviously).

Answer (score 3):

The view file name that is rendered is derived from the controller name, action name and request MIME type.

For example, the `PostsController` action `show` in a regular html request will render the `app/views/posts/show.html.erb` file. A JSON request to the `PostsController#index` renders the `app/views/posts/index.json.jbuilder` view. And so on.

You can explicitly tell the controller to render a different view: `render 'other/view'`, which will render the `app/views/other/view.html.erb` file.

You can also react differently to different request types in the controller action using `respond_to`:

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render 'other/view' }
  format.json { render 'another/view' }
end
```